# Swift BLE peripheral writeValue is not working

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

My current code is:

```
@IBAction func sendData(sender: UISwitch) {
    if advertisingSwitch.on {
        var parameter = NSInteger(45)
        let data = NSData(bytes: &parameter, length: 1)
        if let connectedPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral {
            println("========= In connected peripheral \(connectedPeripheral)")
            //println("========= Send data is \(currentSendData)")
            println("========= Characteristic is \(sendDataCharacteristic)")
            println("========= data length is \(data.bytes)")
            self.sendDataToCentral(connectedPeripheral, characteristic: sendDataCharacteristic!, data: data)
        }
    }
}

private func sendDataToCentral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, characteristic: CBCharacteristic, data: NSData) {
    println("data is \(data)")
    peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
    println("writed characteristic \(characteristic)")
}
```

When I checked the Peripheral, it is connected showing:

```
BPeripheral: 0x1700ee980, identifier = E2377588-84CB-87ED-570A-B51614287B3C, name = TAv22u-FDF1, state = connected
```

The characteristic is getting from service scan with known UUID. I am sure the characteristic I got has function "write", which is

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x174086090, UUID = FFE9, properties = 0x8, value = (null), notifying = NO>
```

after I executing function:

```
peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
```

The value in characteristic is not changing. I don't know where did I get wrong.

Comment: When you say the value isn't changing, how are you verifying this?  From the receiving peripheral or are you just checking the value of the `CBCharacteristic` in the sending central?

Comment: what error do you get in `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` (`CBPeripheralDelegate` method)?

Comment: @Paulw11 I mean I the data is not showing in the receiving peripheral. I have a peripheral receiver that can update the data in the screen.

Comment: @MichałCiuba That function is not even executed.

Comment: If you write `withoutResponse`, `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` shouldn't be called. Try `withResponse` instead? How is set `sendDataCharacteristic`?

Answer (score 1):

```
peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: 
 CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

try `.withResponse` and check what is response from peripheral.